# Powershell script to check for duplicates and modify

Tags: powershell, csv, vbscript

I am dealing with a script that automates the creation of all of the Users on the server by reading a CSV file. The only problem with this is when the user has the same username as someone else. (i.e. jsmith) I would like to find either a powershell or VBScript that can look through my CSV file, find the duplicates,  leave the first one as JSmith and change the second one to JoSmith and the third (if it were there) to JohSmith. I have done this with an excel formula, but then I must import the csv into excel, make sure my formula is copied down far enough and then save the CSV again. This is making my automated script less and less automated since my CSV file is generated from a third party program.

I do not know if this is possible, but I do know that Powershell can look for unique fields and report those back so I thought it might be possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This logic you describe is definitely possible. However we are not a code writing service more a community that helps programmers and programming enthusiasts. Do you have something you started you need help with?

Comment: You need `Group` to fix your woes, and maybe a while loop. If you can make an attempt to fix your issue and post what errors you get, and post the relevant code I'm sure we can help. Consider something like `$users|group UserID|Where{$_.Count -gt 1}|Select -Expand Group|ForEach{While($_.count -ne ($_|select -unique).count){<logic to fix ID's>}}` ...Post your resulting code and issues you get, and we'll see what we can't do to get you running.